# How could I export gridview data to docx (ms word)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, docx

I'm working on asp.net web application development using c#. I am trying to export the Gridview data to **docx** (ms word). But I couldn't do that( 
I did only export data to **doc** format

```
       string FName = "filename.doc";
        mygrid.AllowPaging = false;
        mygrid.DataSource = datasource();
        mygrid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", FName));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        mygrid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

How to do export data from gridview to **docx** format?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this mime type

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

Comment: I did it, but word didn't open the file. It said: 
The file is damaged

Comment: Hmm, did you change the filename as well?